# How to change form field label in Django using template language only?

Tags: django, django-forms

I have tried using django-widget-tweaks to override default form field attributes, where you can set various form field attributes like this:

```
{{ form.username|attr:"name:email"|as_crispy_field}}
```

but when I inspect the element in the Chrome Dev Tools I can see that the element still has the default `username` name attribute.
I was trying to change the name attribute so that the label for this field would display "Email" instead of "Username".

So I was wondering if there is a way to change Django form field label using Django template language only?

3rd party tools are OK too.

Comment: You talk about changing the _label_ but your code attempts to change the `name` attribute of the field, which for good reasons (the form will not be able to find the field otherwise) widget-tweaks won't allow you to change.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat yes, I was thinking of changing the `name` attribute of the field so that the `label` field would pick it up and display it. I can see your point, so maybe there is another option to change to `label` directly?

Comment: In that case just render the label separately yourself in the HTML. Anyway the limitation "using Django template language only" will stop most answers since even if one would think about writing a custom template tag it would need _python_ code for that. Also why even do so much? Simply set the proper label in the form class...